# vector<pair<double,double>> giving problems

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<pair<double, double> > Vec; //cords vector (0.0,0.0)/(x,y)
typedef pair<double, double> Punto; //single coord

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "cuants vertex?" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    Vec V[x]; // Declare vector of pairs as long as user wants
    Punto P;
    for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++) { //fill vector with coords
        cout << "Introdueix coordenada numero: " << i;
        cout << "x: ";
        cin >> P.first;
        cout << "y: ";
        cin >> P.second;
        V.push_back(P);
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < V.size(); c++) { //show all coords
        P.first = V[c].first;
        P.second = V[c].second;
        cout << P.first << P.second << endl;
    }
}
```

This is a simple code filling a `vector<pair<double,double>>`, it gives this errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:18: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘V’, which is of non-class type ‘Vec [x] {aka std::vector > [x]}’
   for(int i=0;i<V.size(); i++){
                   ^~~~
main.cpp:19:5: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘V’, which is of non-class type ‘Vec [x] {aka std::vector > [x]}’
    V.push_back(P);
      ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:21:19: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘V’, which is of non-class type ‘Vec [x] {aka std::vector > [x]}’  
for(int c=0; c<V.size(); c++){
                 ^~~~
main.cpp:22:16: error: ‘Vec {aka class std::vector >}’ has no member named ‘first’
    P.first=V[c].first;
                 ^~~~~
main.cpp:23:17: error: ‘Vec {aka class std::vector >}’ has no member named ‘second’; did you mean ‘end’?   
P.second=V[c].second;
              ^~~~~~
```

Any way to solve it?

Comment: "Declare vector of pairs" does not declare a vector of pairs. That actually declares an array of vector of pairs. That's the root cause of your problems.

Comment: `Vec V[x];` defines an array object -- but only if your C++ compiler supports variable-length arrays as an extension. `V` should just be a `Vec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
Vec V[x]; // Declare vector of pairs as long as user wants
```

Is actually creating a C-style array of `Vec`, not a single `Vec`. You should use round parentheses instead, constructing a single `Vec`:

```
Vec V(x); // Declare vector of pairs as long as user wants
```

However, now `push_back` will add additional elements. Replace

```
V.push_back(P);
```

with

```
V[i] = P;
```

Comment: thank u very much dude long time without programming... little mistakes hahahah.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vec V[x];
```

`x` is not a constant expression, so you are declaring a variable-length array.  This is a compiler extension and is not C++.  And an array cannot have `.size()` member.

You need to change it to:

```
Vec V;
```

(Also, use `Vec::size_type` to go through the vector, or you will get a signedness warning.)

Comment: The first part is helpful to know, but not completely the problem here. Although, UB is UB, so there's that...

Comment: @Chipster It's not UB; it's ill-formed.

Comment: Using a non constant value in an array is not UB?

Comment: @Chipster It doesn't compile if you turn off the extension.  Only well-formed code can be UB.

Comment: @Chipster Yes, it won't compile on a "vanilla" compiler.

Comment: @L.F. Nope, you're right. [It is ill-formed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), not UB. Also, it just clicked what you're saying about how only well-formed code is UB. I got you now.